# Expandable and Scrollable Floating Action Button Flutter

Tags: flutter, expandablelistview, floating-action-button, scrollable

I'm Trying to Build an App but I'm stuck at the floating action button.
I have tried to create custom floating action using the animated builder.

This is what I want to achieve
[[image: This Is what I want to achieve]]

Comment: May be this give you heads up https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/effects/expandable-fab